# trying to access the schemas imported in a WSDL file

Tags: xml, web-services, wsdl, schema

I am trying to ge tthe schemas imported in my WSDL file:

```
WSDLReader reader = WSDLFactory.newInstance().newWSDLReader();
            reader.setFeature ("javax.wsdl.verbose", false);
        reader.setFeature ("javax.wsdl.importDocuments",true);

        Definition def = reader.readWSDL("./wsdl/PrepaidAdmin.wsdl");
        System.out.println(def.getTypes());
                System.out.println("def.getExtensibilityElements().size()="+def.getExtensibilityElements().size());
```

This is the output of Sysout:

```
Sourcefile:/D:/WorkSpace/XSD Validation/wsdl/PrepaidAdmin.wsdl
Types:
SchemaExtensibilityElement ({http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}schema):
required=null
element=[xsd:schema: null]
SchemaExtensibilityElement ({http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}schema):
required=null
element=[xsd:schema: null]
```

I dont understand why I am getting null when the WSDL has two schemas imported?Plz help

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:

```
Map mp = new HashMap();

            for( Object o : def.getTypes().getExtensibilityElements()) {
                if( o instanceof javax.wsdl.extensions.schema.Schema ) {
                 //   org.w3c.dom.Element elt = ((javax.wsdl.extensions.schema.SchemaImport) o) //.getElement();
                    Schema sc = (javax.wsdl.extensions.schema.Schema) o;
                    mp.put(sc.getElement().getNamespaceURI(),sc);
                    mp.putAll(sc.getImports());
                    System.out.println(mp);
                                    //++i;
                    } 
            }
```